# How do you activate a troll's variant rule: Loathsome Limbs?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters

The Monster Manual states that when a Troll takes 15 slashing damage **at one time**, it loses one of its limbs.

### What does "at one time" mean?

Is it one weapon attack, as I suspect, or does a multiattack of at least 15 slashing damage activate the effect?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

At one time implies a single attack. If you use multiattack it is multiple blows, of which you can even move between and therefore the attacks do not occur at one time. They are split up between multiple times over the period of your 6 second turn.

The 15 damage indicates that the blow is severe enough to remove the limb. If it was over multiple attacks you would need to strike the exact same spot a second time to go through which is unlikely.

Comment: I was reading through some similar topics, and I read about Massive Damage and System Shock in page 273 of the DMG. It says "When a creature takes damage from a *single source* equal to or greater than half its hit point maximum...". I'm assuming, holding true to the answer, that it also means one weapon attack?

Comment: Tashio: while your reasoning makes sense, it could also imply a single Action.  If you have a double melee attack with two short swords as one Action, the "one-two" of blows landing in the same area could weaken the joint with the second finishing the job.  In this case the single source is the single rogue or fighter landing two quick blows in the same spot.  "Exact same spot" as a criteria seems overly arbitrary.

Comment: Ultimately it's going to be one of those DM's call until there is a clarification from the designers. The joys of no standardised terminology, for certain things. Exact same spot maybe not quite the best wording, but an attempt to put it into perspective.

Comment: Tashio: fair point, and your answer has the virtue of using the KISS principle.